How can I customize cache key for ROOT_QUERY in Apollo InMemoryCache?
I'm trying to configure InMemoryCache so that ROOT_QUERY has the same key whether a variable is null or undefined (or not passed at all, but that seems to be the same as undefined).
I've tried to use typePolicies:
const cache = new InMemoryCache({
  typePolicies: {
    Query: {
      keyFields: (object, context) => ...
    }
  }
});

but when logging this function never seems to be called. RootQuery or ROOT_QUERY instead of Query don't work either.
Is this possible? Or would I need to subclass InMemoryCache instead?
